# Javascript code editor in dynamically scaled container

Tags: javascript, css, ace-editor, codemirror, monaco-editor

I'm trying to display functional code editor in a container which scale and translation will be modified at runtime, its rotation and proportion wont be touch no skew either. Document structure is generated at runtime but relevant part looks like this:

```
<div id="container" style="transform: scale(2)">
    <div id="editor-element">
        <!-- stuff generated by editor implementation -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried codemirror, ace, monaco, I've been able to apply translation without problems but after scaling all of them exhibits the same problem - cursor inside editor was displayed incorrectly making them really hard to use.
I tried either css transform approach and svg foreignObject.

Does anyone know if there is an editor that could work or if there is a way to fix one of mentioned editors?

Example of incorrectly displayed cursor at scale x2 in codemirror - wrong place and size, should be after `rel`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filling some issues i finally got my answers.

- codemirror: it is know [issue](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/2443) that wont't be fixed anytime soon
- ace - [master branch](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) contains patches fixing problem with scaling but mouse event are still on the way.
- monaco - existing [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+transform) but no apparent fix

So for now best results gives **ace** and it looks like in near future it will have perfect css transform support.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of CodeMirror (and probably Ace and Monaco too), the problem comes from the internal use of `getBoundingClientRect`, which doesn't consider CSS transformations in its calculations (check [here](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/2443)). This is an old problem on the Web, specially for esoteric applications such as text editors. For all I know, there is no sane way of patching the method nor browser vendors seem to be willing to provide an alternative.

Fortunately, there is a workaround that might suffice for your use case. It did for mine. If you wrap CodeMirror in an iframe, `getBoundingClientRect` will return the correct results because it will consider the transformations the iframe window is subject to.

A created a CodePen demonstrating the full concept:

https://codepen.io/samuelmtimbo/pen/dyXgpaV

Here is the important part of the code:

```js
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.onload = () => {
  const _window = iframe.contentWindow;
  const _document = _window.document;
  const _body = _document.body;

  const _div = _document.createElement("div");
  _body.appendChild(_div);

  const link = _document.createElement("link");
  link.href =
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/codemirror.min.css";
  link.rel = "stylesheet";
  _body.appendChild(link);

  const script = _document.createElement("script");
  script.src =
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/codemirror.min.js";
  script.onload = () => {
    const codeMirror = _window.CodeMirror(_div, {
      value: "function main() {}\n",
      mode: "javascript"
    });
  };
  _body.appendChild(script);
};
```